# How to retrieve a subset of array within an object in a meteor collection?

Tags: meteor

Hope someone can help! I have a collection in meteor which has objects which contain arrays of temperature readings in the following format:

```
   "temp_readings": [
        {
            "reading_time": {
                "$date": "2015-01-18T11:54:00.700Z"
            },
            "temp_F": 181.76
        },
        {
            "reading_time": {
                "$date": "2015-01-18T11:55:00.700Z"
            },
            "temp_F": 187.16
        },
        {
            "reading_time": {
                "$date": "2015-01-18T11:56:00.700Z"
            },
            "temp_F": 190.76
        },
        {
            "reading_time": {
                "$date": "2015-01-18T11:57:00.700Z"
            },
            "temp_F": 196.16
        }
    ]
```

I can retrieve this complete array in my client side meteor code but I now want to read just a subset of this array based on a date/time which is being set by the user. So for example retrieve the subset of the array which has only entries equal or later than "2015-01-18T11:56:00.700Z"... I know I could probably do something with selective publish/subscribe methods but for now is there a simple way on the client side to retrieve this subset of data? Maybe some javascript methods can help?

Thanks in advance,
Rick

Comment: You can specify this in your find query, with $in operator as shown in this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// or however you fetch your document
var doc = MyCollection.findOne();

if (!doc)
  return [];

// ensure temps is an array
var temps = doc.temp_readings || [];

// return an array of temp readings where the date is > someOtherDate
return _.filter(temps, function(temp) {
  return temp.reading_time.$date > someOtherDate;
});
```

Comment: Thanks David! I just had to make a minor alteration but your code worked great otherwise :-)  I just had to change the line :  
`return temp.reading_time.$date > someOtherDate;`  
to  
`return temp.reading_time > someOtherDate;`  
Turns out I didn't need to add the $date in there...  
Thanks again,  
Rick